# Decreasing a Timer every Second, both integers are decreasing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to implement a Score System into my Game. I got two variables,

```
public int maxScore; 
public int currentScore;
```

To set the currentScore, I get the maxScore and throw it into currentScore:

```
currentScore = maxScore;
```

So the Player has the maximum amount of points if he starts the Game. If he now is to slow, I decrease the currentPoints *per Second* with

```
IEnumerator CurrentScore()
{
        currentScore -= 1;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); //I'm using 5, because 1 does not equals a second
}
```

and call it by saying

```
StartCoroutine(CurrentScore());
```

If I now look into the Game, it all looks fine:

As the Game starts, both are on 3000:

[image: On start of the Game]

If the timer runs to a specific value, the currentScore decreases, but the MaxScore stays. As it should:

[image]

However, as soon as the WinScreen PopsUp, both values start to decrease rapidly, instead of only one decreasing:

[image]

I have this script Attached to the Text that shows the Current (Earned) Points, and the Possible Points:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class WinScreenScore : MonoBehaviour {
    //Load the classes
    public GameManager manager;
    //To get our Text
    //public GameObject scoreText;
    Text max;
    Text current;
    //As soon as the Thread awakes, load the Text
    void Awake()
    {
        max = GetComponent<Text>();
        max.text = manager.maxScore.ToString();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        current = GetComponent<Text>();
        current.text = manager.currentScore.ToString();
    }
}
```

Script on the Text which displays the currentScore (Earned Points):

[image]

And on the Possible Points:

[image]

I can't figure out why both values are decreasing rapidly after the Winscreen got shown.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: So you *never* assign `maxScore` ?

Comment: Where are you starting the coroutine from?

Comment: @gjttt1From the same Class as the Coroutine is in, my GameManager.cs

Comment: I assign my `maxScore` in the WinScreenScore, in `void Awake()` (Code under the first image in my Post) @ThomasAyoub

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, the question is when/where do you assign a value to `maxScore`?

Comment: hi @DanielKng - this is completely wrong.  To make timers in Unity you just use `Invoke` or perhaps `InvokeRepeating`.  (There's also the handy `CancelInvoke`.)  Google for some code samples.  You would never use anything as complicated as coroutines for this; you'll be tying yourself in knots.   Unity is *very easy to use*, it's "for kids" you know?   Just use Invoke.

Comment: @JoeBlow Haha, thanks for the Tip! Works better than my Coroutine. Then there is still my Problem with both timers decreasing left :)

Comment: @JoeBlow Why you hating on coroutines like that my man.

Comment: hi big UR .. it's just that for yourself and me, coroutines.  But beginners tie themselves in knots with them.  Let's put it this way: they should first master  Invoke and other simple techniques.  My $0.02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinScreenScore runs on both text objects.
In the Update method, you get the component that is Text and set it to the current score. So for you max score this is happening. The awake gets the text component and sets the text to the max score from the game manager. Then in the update, you set THE SAME text component to the current score. Basically, you are filling max and current with the same text component. Solution : create public references to the game objects that hold the text components and then get the two separate texts. The script does not need to run on both objects.

CodeExample :

```
public GameManager manager;
public GameObject max, achieved;
Text currentText, maxText;
void Start()
{
    currentText = achieved.GetComponent<Text>();
    maxText = max.GetComponent<Text>();
    maxText.text = manager.maxScore.ToString();
}
//Since the current Score needs to be updated
void FixedUpdate()
{
    currentText.text = manager.currentScore.ToString();
}
```

Now you can set current and max independently. Also using GetComponent in Update is a bad idea since its a heavy operation. Try to use only in places that run once.

Comment: Can you post a Code-Example on how to `get the two separate Texts`?
I created the reference with 
`public WinScreenScore EarnedScore;

  public WinScreenScore MaxScore;`

Comment: @DanielKng I updated my answer. You want to get the gameObjects that hold the text components not the instances of the scripts that run on the gameObjects.